# Tkinter window will not close upon clicking a button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

(I apologize for the naive question)

I have a window that pops up that allows a user to select two months as a starting point and end point for data collection.

[image]

The events that occur with the click of the 'OK' button are to return a list and dictionary of the months in between the selected range, and to notify the user of their selected range. However, I would like this window to close after clicking 'OK' as well. The events are under the `callback` function. I cannot make `root.destroy` reachable.

*All the code that is involved is here. My function `callback` is towards the bottom:*

```
from tkinter import *

startDate = 'Dec 16'
now = datetime.now()
endDate = now.strftime('%b %y')
start = datetime.strptime(startDate, '%b %y').date()
end = datetime.strptime(endDate, '%b %y').date()
cur_date = start
range_months = []

while cur_date < end:
    cur_date += relativedelta(months=1)
    range_months.append(cur_date)

range_months = [month.strftime('%b %y') for month in range_months]
dict_months = dict((month, pd.to_datetime(month, format='%b %y')) for month in range_months)

root = Tk()
#root.withdraw()
root.title("Select your Month Range")

# Setting up Grid
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.pack(pady=50, padx=50)
Label(mainframe, text="Select Start Month").grid(row=1, column=1)
Label(mainframe, text="Select End Month").grid(row=1, column=6)

# Creating two Tkinter variables to obtain user input from the drop down menus
tkvar_start = StringVar(root)
tkvar_end = StringVar(root)
tkvar_start.set('Jan 17')  # Setting a default option
tkvar_end.set(endDate)

start_popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar_start, *dict_months)
end_popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar_end, *dict_months)
start_popupMenu.grid(row=2, column=1)
end_popupMenu.grid(row=2, column=6)


def callback_range():
    print('The range is from %s to %s' % (tkvar_start.get(), tkvar_end.get()))
    list_of_month_keys = list(dict_months.keys())
    import itertools
    range_dict_months = dict(itertools.islice(dict_months.items(), list_of_month_keys.index(tkvar_start.get()),
                                       list_of_month_keys.index(tkvar_end.get()) + 1))

    return list_of_month_keys, range_dict_months


button = Button(mainframe, text = "OK", command = callback_range)
button.grid(row=3, column=23)

root.mainloop()
list_of_month_keys, range_dict_months = callback_range()
```

**How can I make `root.destroy()` reachable in my function `callback`, while still returning `list_of_month_keys` and `range_dict_months`, in order to additionally close this window upon clicking 'OK'?**

Comment: You can't. The function will stop executing after it completes a return statement. You will need to rework your program to close the GUI window after you have processed the data.

Comment: Your last line of code `list_of_month_keys, range_dict_months = callback_range()` will never work. The reason for this is due to your function `callback_range()` being inside of your tkinter mainloop and your last line of code will never be able to execute this function. Even when the mainloop terminates everything that was inside of that loop is also gone.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to get into your program and came up with that solution.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as mb
from datetime import datetime
import itertools
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd

class MonthRangeWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        startDate='Dec 16'
        endDate=datetime.now().strftime('%b %y')
        cur_date=start=datetime.strptime(startDate,'%b %y').date()
        end=datetime.strptime(endDate,'%b %y').date()
        range_months=[]
        self.list_of_month_keys,self.range_dict_months=None,None

        while cur_date<end:
            cur_date+=relativedelta(months=1)
            range_months.append(cur_date)

        range_months=[month.strftime('%b %y') for month in range_months]
        self.dict_months=dict((month,pd.to_datetime(month,format='%b %y')) for month in range_months)

        self.root=Tk()
        #self.root.withdraw()
        self.root.title("Select your Month Range")

        mainframe=Frame(self.root)
        mainframe.pack(pady=50,padx=50)

        Label(mainframe,text="Select Start Month").grid(row=1,column=1)
        Label(mainframe,text="Select End Month").grid(row=1,column=6)

        self.tkvar_start=StringVar(root,'Jan 17')
        self.tkvar_end=StringVar(root,endDate)
        start_popupMenu=OptionMenu(mainframe,tkvar_start,*self.dict_months)
        end_popupMenu=OptionMenu(mainframe,tkvar_end,*self.dict_months)
        start_popupMenu.grid(row=2,column=1)
        end_popupMenu.grid(row=2,column=6)

        button=Button(mainframe,text="Ok",command=self.callback_range)
        button.grid(row=3,column=23)

    def callback_range(self):
        mb.showinfo(title='Info',message='The range is from %s to %s.' % (self.tkvar_start.get(),self.tkvar_end.get()),master=self.root)
        self.list_of_month_keys=list(self.dict_months.keys())
        self.range_dict_months=dict(itertools.islice(self.dict_months.items(),self.list_of_month_keys.index(self.tkvar_start.get()),self.list_of_month_keys.index(self.tkvar_end.get()) + 1))

    def mainloop(self,n=0):
        self.root.mainloop(n)
        return self.list_of_month_keys,self.range_dict_months

if __name__=='__main__':
    mrw=MonthRangeWindow()
    list_of_month_keys,range_dict_months=mrw.mainloop()
    print(list_of_month_keys,range_dict_months)
```

Since I don't have the pandas module for that `pd.to_datetime(...)` and I'm too lazy to download it I were not able to test it. But I think you should be able to debug it if needed.

And I also allowed myself, to insert an infowindow from tkinters messagebox module instead of `print`. If you don't want this just replace it by print again.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to bind multiple commands to the button.

```
def combined_functions(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func

//close the mainframe
def close_window():
    mainframe.quit()

button = Button(mainframe, text = "OK", command = combined_functions(callback_range, close_window))
```

Also, it is probably not a very good idea to import a module in the middle of a method. And the code would look much better if you split the `range_dict_months` into separate lines.